# Losing my git commit

Tags: git

i am currently facing an issue with a commit in GIT.

i have two branches within my repository:

origin/master
origin/dev

i checked out the origin/dev via
git checkout origin/dev

then i did my changes in a file (change file permission) and was doing following:
git add fileName
git commit -m "File name changed"

When i am now changing the code branch to 
git checkout origin/master i am getting following error message:
you are leaving 1 commit behind....

I thought i commit everything.
If i am doing that with origin/master, it takes over all the changes.

Answer (score 0):

`origin/master` is a **remote** branch. You should not be checking those out. You need to make local branches which track your remote branches.

You should be using `git checkout master`, *not* `git checkout origin/master`. And you should use `git checkout dev`, *not* `git checkout origin/dev`.

When you use `git checkout origin/master`, you're checking out the **commit** pointed to by that branch. When you commit changes, you're making a new commit with no branch pointing to it. Committing in this state does *not* modify `origin/master`.

Comment: Hi changed it now and it works. But i don't really understood your last sentences. When you use git checkout origin/master, you're checking out the commit pointed to by that branch. When you commit changes, you're making a new commit with no branch pointing to it. Committing in this state does not modify origin/master.